# Can I default the keyboard to use the symbols instead of numbers?

Tags: keyboard, keybindings

I type <kbd>@</kbd> or <kbd>$</kbd> or <kbd>&</kbd> or <kbd>*</kbd> way more often than I do <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>4</kbd>, <kbd>7</kbd> or <kbd>8</kbd>.

Especially with <kbd>(</kbd><kbd>)</kbd> it is usually a bit more difficult to hit <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> <kbd>9</kbd> and immediately <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd> + <kbd>0</kbd>.

Can I somehow default the numeric keys to print the <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>ed values by default, and print the digits when I actually use <kbd>⇧Shift</kbd>?

This is not remapping of values, this is using the modifier key always for certain keys. This is not a duplicate, I do not want to use Ukelele for this.

Comment: Per your edit....no matter how you slice it, you're remapping the default action of the key.

Comment: @Allan I am asking if it is possible to achieve this without remapping. Those targets are already there, I am asking if I can switch the secondary behaviour with first one for particular keys.

Comment: Why is remapping a problem for you?  I could do this in ukelele in 5 minutes or less..  Never heard of a way to do what you are talking about.

Comment: @TomGewecke Ok, maybe it is not possible. But I think it is totally ok to ask if it is possible or not, isn 't it? If you are sure what I am asking is not possible, please simply provide an answer like: `No there is no such way` and let me accept it.

Comment: @KorayTugay.  No.  What you are asking is very much possible.  It's called **remapping a key.**  You can redefine it however you like to suit your tastes, but in the end, **it's the exact same process as remapping a key.**  Therefore, it's a dupe.

Comment: @KorayTugay Ukelele is the normal way to do this.  Here is one:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/we6pz6m1sdxg39b/U.S.NumShift.keylayout.zip?dl=0

Comment: I think what you are asking is something like this `defaults write -g com.apple.keyboard.fnState true` which activates the Fn keys, I have not found one for the numbers

Comment: @Allan It is said you are unable to understand.

Comment: @Buscar웃 Yes, that is what I am looking for.

Comment: You can kind of do it if you swap your keyboard to French... but that will give you azerty too.

Comment: @Tetsujin That is a very big side effect. :)

Comment: Yup, so you're back to Ukelele...